# What determines the look of a Web Push Notification?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, browser, push-notification

What is responsible for how the notification looks like? Is it the browser or the operating system?

I am pretty sure that *somehow* both, for two reasons:

1. Chrome, Firefox, or Opera shows completely different notifications
2. The notifications look different on different platforms (Win, OSX, Linux)

As far as I know, it's the browser's service worker which is responsible for handling the `push` event, so my guess is that it's also the browser which is styling the notification, but it doesn't explain to me why does it look different on various platforms. The same notification on the same version of Chrome looks different for instance on Ubuntu Mate and Arch + KDE Plasma.

So my question is what determines the look of it? If browser, then why does the notification look different on various OSes? If it's OS, then why does it look different on each browser?

Comment: Some screenshots would be interesting to see :) Although I'm with you in that it's probably just a bit of both